# How to fix Join(" ") doesnt add a space to the concatenated string

Tags: c#, .net

When i try to Join() an array with words and try to add a space to it,
The space seems to be left out, any idea why?

A little background info, when i try to reverse a string of words given to me so that

"hi my name is" should become "is name my hi"

```
public static string ReverseWords(string text)
{
    string[] words = text.Split(' ');
    string s = "";

    for (int i = words.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
       s+= string.Join(" ", words [i]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

The expected outcome would have been: "world! hello"
  But it was:  "world!hello"

As you can see I'm missing the space between world! and hello.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you observed when you attached the debugger in your IDE and inspected the variables? That should be the first thing you learn how to do, learning how to debug your own code. That will not only make you a better programmer it will allow you to fix many of these "simple" mistakes / logic errors yourself as you are writing and testing your code (as opposed to posting them on [so]).

Comment: Why not simply `Join` a reversed array instead of joining inside the loop? Your current code effectively works against the comfort `Join()` provides.

Comment: `words[i]` returds a single string.

Comment: You're using join on each single word, which just gives you the word back again, and then you're manually concatenating those. Do the `join` on your whole string array. That's what it's for. Get rid of your `for` loop.

Comment: About learning how to debug your code at run time: Here are a few of the many resources available: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), and [Debugging C# Code in Visual Studio | Mosh](https://youtu.be/u-HdLtqEOog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry that it took me a while guys, im still a beginner.
But the .Reverse() function wasnt it because it would turn every char in the word backwards, which wasnt my objective.

The trick was as following:

```
public static string ReverseWords(string text)
{  
string[] words = text.Split(' ');
string s = words[words.Length - 1];

for (int i = words.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
  s+= " " + words[i];
}
return s; 
}
}
```

really alot of thanks with guiding.
@igor you where right, i kept trying to do this exercise in an online environment when i copied it to VS i could discover what was wrong by slowly debugging.

Answer (score 12):

You're calling `Join` with a single word at a time, using the [overload accepting a parameter array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___). Joining a single item will always just return that item - there's nothing else to join it with.

Instead of that, just call it with *all* the words, in reverse order:

```
public static string ReverseWords(string text)
{
    string[] words = text.Split(' ');
    return string.Join(" ", words.Reverse());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Join combines the elements of the array with the specified separator, but you are adding each element separately. So no space is added.

```
string.Join(" ", words.Reverse());
```

Answer (score 3):

string.Join() is designed to work on a list of strings, placing the separator char between each. You're only giving it one at a time, hence no separator. Try this:

```
public static string ReverseWords(string text)
{
    string[] words = text.Split(' ');

    return string.Join(" ", words.Reverse());
}
```